# How to render a table properly in html/RMarkdown with numbers in brackets

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

The table that gets rendered using the code below doesn't display correctly for the values that are less than 1,000. The values greater than 1,000 look like this: `(1,234)`, which is what I am expecting, whereas the ones below 1,000 look like this: `999.`

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
dt <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                 test = c("a", "b", "c"),
                 header1 = c("(1,234)", "(999)", "(4,543)"),
                 header.2 = c("(1,674)", "(123)", "(4,423)"))
dt %>%
  kable("html") %>%
  kable_styling()
```
````

Is there a simple fix? Keeping the brackets is preferable.

```
> sessioninfo::session_info()
- Session info -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United Kingdom.1252 
 ctype    English_United Kingdom.1252 
 tz       Europe/London               
 date     2019-11-04                  

- Packages ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package     * version date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 cli           1.1.0   2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 rstudioapi    0.10    2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)

[1] C:/Users/***********/Documents/R/R-3.6.1/library
> sessioninfo::session_info()
- Session info -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United Kingdom.1252 
 ctype    English_United Kingdom.1252 
 tz       Europe/London               
 date     2019-11-04                  

- Packages ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package     * version date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 cli           1.1.0   2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 digest        0.6.22  2019-10-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 htmltools     0.3.6   2017-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 knitr         1.25    2019-09-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 Rcpp          1.0.2   2019-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 rmarkdown     1.15    2019-08-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 rsconnect     0.8.15  2019-07-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 rstudioapi    0.10    2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 xfun          0.9     2019-08-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 yaml          2.2.0   2018-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to "escape" the values that are causing problems with `\\`.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
dt <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                 test = c("a", "b", "c"),
                 header1 = c("(1,234)", "\\(999)", "(4,543)"),
                 header.2 = c("(1,674)", "\\(123)", "(4,423)"))
dt %>%
  kable("html") %>% 
  kable_styling()
```
````

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This doesn't fix it for me. Perhaps OS-related? I get the same with just `dt %>% kable("html")` too

Comment: You are quite right - I had another look and I think you need to 'escape' the values, so I edited my answer, hopefully that should do it.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I've only just joined StackOverflow so my upvote isn't visible publicly yet, but I've marked this as the answer